# WHOAMI in SED command

Tags: shell

whoami|cut -c5,6,7----gives dev

sed -e 's@man[a-zA-Z]*@man`whoami|cut -c5,6,7`@g' file_name.txt
##whoami|cut -c5,6,7 is in  between ``

with this I am geting manwhoami|cut -c5,6,7 instead of mandev in the file.

file_name.txt
LogFile=/manrun/in/get/new1/

after I run
$sed -e 's@man[a-zA-Z]*@man`whoami|cut -c5,6,7`@g' file_name.txt

I am geting as below:
$cat file_name.txt
LogFile=/man`whoami|cut -c5,6,7`/in/get/new1/
I need LogFile=/mandev/in/get/new1/

any inputs plz.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your stuff inside '' then it will not be evaluated.

To evaluate a command you put it as $(command)

I suggest you to store the command result into a variable and then reference the variable in the sed expression.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Lucas Eduardo, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
BASE=$(whoami|cut -c5,6,7)
sed -e "s@man[a-zA-Z]*@man${BASE}@g" file_name.txt
```

In the comments you have mentioned it did not work for you, that is because you were using single quotes and thus the substitution was not made. Notice in my code I use double quotes and so the substitution will occur.

Hope this helped you!